# Fail to 'git pull' using LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, authorization, credentials, libgit2sharp

I have the following piece of code, that is meant to pull changes from the current branch:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var repo = new Repository(args[0]);
        var signaure = repo.Config.BuildSignature(DateTimeOffset.Now);
        var pullResult = Commands.Pull(repo, signaure, new PullOptions());
    }
```

I get this exception when I run this:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
Exception occured: LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: request failed with status code: 401
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_remote_fetch(RemoteHandle remote, IEnumerable`1 refSpecs, GitFetchOptions fetchOptions, String logMessage)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Commands.Fetch(Repository repository, String remote, IEnumerable`1 refspecs, FetchOptions options, String logMessage)
   at LibGit2Sharp.Commands.Pull(Repository repository, Signature merger, PullOptions options)
```

I tried to search online, couldn't figure out how to solve this (most of the results used an outdated API). If I simple type "git pull" in cmd (from the repo folder) it works. Any help?

Comment: `git pull` on commandline succeeds? Maybe you need to provide credentials to access that repository, that's what 401 is, unauthorized error.

Comment: Yes. I thought so, I just don't understand how to provide credentials using this API (and also why would I if it works via the cmd)

Comment: git saves credentials the first time you clone a repository. This lib might not be asking you for one. Read docs about how to provide creds.

Comment: I honestly couldn't find a decent working documentation or a discussion about how to do this. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate.